# drupal 7 popup window (or how to show links disabled)

Tags: popup, drupal-7

I'm just starting drupal and I have a question.  I have a main menu but some links/sections have no content yet, and I want to show a pop up window with a 'coming soon' legend when the user clicks it.  However the only [module](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_popupwindow) that might help does not work with D7 yet and I don't know if there's a way to do it manually.

If it weren't possible, is there a way to have these links without content still appear but have them disabled so users can't click them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it but this might help you:

```php
drupal_add_js('window.open(url, "name", "height=512, width=512").focus();', 
               array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5));
```

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7